# Double inequality constraint in Gekko

Tags: python, gekko

I have an optimization problem in which some inequalities constraints can either be 0 or greater than a certain value. For example, in the code below, `qtde` and `c1` are lists and `pp` is a 2d numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

qtde = [7, 2, 2, 12, 2, 7, 1.5, 8, 4, 16, 2, 1, 3, 0.2, 3, 1, 1, 10, 8, 5, 3, 2.5, 5, 2.5, 10, 3, 1, 6, 12, 2, 6, 1, 4, 1, 2, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1]
c1 = [26.0, 150.0, 300.0, 110.0, 400.0, 500.0, 200.0, 200.0, 27.0, 150.0, 50.0, 200.0, 75.0, 0.0, 250.0, 22.8, 300.0, 22.8, 22.8, 150.0, 300.0, 150.0, 100.0, 100.0, 1000.0, 150.0, 150.0, 200.0, 31.2, 100.0, 100.0, 50.0, 23.0, 300.0, 200.0, 300.0, 0.0, 300.0, 30.0, 26.0, 300.0, 300.0, 250.0, 100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 400.0, 21.2, 200.0, 500.0, 0.0]

mm = [[4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,2,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,15,0,0,16,0,0,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[29,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,0,0,31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,0,0,33,0,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,37,0,0,0,36,0,0,0,38,0,0,0,39,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,35,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[42,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,0,0,44,0,43,0,0,0,49,0,0,0,46,0,0,0,47,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45,0,41,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,54,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,53,0,0,0,52,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,51,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,60,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,56,0,0,0,59,0,0,0,57,0,0,0,58,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,55,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[69,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,68,0,0,0,0,0,61,0,0,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,63,0,0,0,65,0,0,0,0,0,0,67,0,0,62,0,66,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,71,0,70,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,78,0,0,0,0,0,77,0,0,0,0,0,73,0,0,0,76,0,0,0,75,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,74,0,72,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,0,0,0,79,0,0,0,82,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,83,0,81,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,86,0,0,0,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,85,0,87,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[93,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,95,0,0,0,0,0,94,0,92,0,0,0,90,0,0,0,91,0,0,0,96,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,89,0,88,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[104,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,0,0,0,0,0,99,0,98,0,0,0,103,0,0,0,101,0,0,0,102,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,97,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[112,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,108,0,0,0,0,0,110,0,107,0,0,0,111,0,0,0,109,0,0,0,113,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,106,0,105,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,116,0,0,0,0,0,117,0,119,0,0,0,115,0,0,0,118,0,0,0,120,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,121,0,122,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,123,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,129,0,0,0,0,126,0,0,0,0,0,0,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,127,125,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,130,0,0,0,0,0,124,0,131,0,0,0],
[0,133,0,0,0,0,136,0,0,0,0,0,0,135,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,132,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,134,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,138,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,137,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,139,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,140,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,141],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,142,0,143,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,144,0,0,0,150,0,146,0,149,0,0,0,0,0,0,152,0,0,0,145,0,0,0,0,147,0,0,151,0,0,0,0,0,148],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,154,0,0,0,0,0,153,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,155,0,0,0,157,0,0,156,0,0,0,158,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,160,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,159,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,161,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,164,0,0,163,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,162,0],
[0,0,165,0,0,0,0,0,0,166,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,167,169,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,170,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,168,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,173,0,0,0,0,0,0,175,177,0,0,171,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,174,172,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,180,0,0,178,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,179,0],
[0,0,0,0,182,184,0,186,0,0,0,183,185,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,181,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,190,191,0,0,187,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,189,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,188,0],
[0,0,193,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,192,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,197,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,196,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,195,0,0,194,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,199,0,0,0,0,201,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,198,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,203,0,0,0,0,204,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,202,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

mm = np.array(mm)
#
pp = [[5.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,7.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,5.49,0.00,2.89,0.00,0.00,0.00,5.98,0.00,0.00,0.00,5.94,0.00,0.00,0.00,6.21,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,3.55,0.00,2.89,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,5.70,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,3.61,0.00,0.00,0.00,5.80,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,3.15,0.00,3.15,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,15.95,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,14.00,11.95,0.00,0.00,12.36,0.00,0.00,14.18,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[3.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,3.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2.20,0.00,0.00,0.00,2.80,0.00,0.00,0.00,2.29,0.00,0.00,0.00,2.27,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2.61,0.00,2.20,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[3.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,9.76,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,5.70,0.00,0.00,6.47,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,7.47,0.00,0.00,8.51,0.00,3.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,10.50,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,9.52,0.00,0.00,0.00,9.10,0.00,0.00,0.00,9.57,0.00,0.00,0.00,9.62,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,9.10,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[6.75,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,9.50,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,7.98,0.00,6.99,0.00,0.00,0.00,11.05,0.00,0.00,0.00,8.55,0.00,0.00,0.00,8.88,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,8.27,0.00,6.75,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,11.20,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,10.95,0.00,0.00,0.00,9.75,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,9.63,0.00,9.16,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,3.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.69,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.98,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.77,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.96,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.69,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[10.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,7.10,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.59,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.95,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.74,0.00,0.00,0.00,2.09,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,6.43,0.00,0.00,1.70,0.00,2.83,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,9.93,0.00,9.93,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,18.40,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,14.49,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,12.89,0.00,0.00,0.00,14.36,0.00,0.00,0.00,13.76,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,13.48,0.00,11.91,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,9.39,0.00,0.00,0.00,7.97,0.00,0.00,0.00,9.57,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,10.24,0.00,9.49,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,33.35,0.00,0.00,0.00,14.80,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,18.00,0.00,72.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[5.70,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,6.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,5.78,0.00,4.50,0.00,0.00,0.00,3.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,4.06,0.00,0.00,0.00,6.46,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,3.55,0.00,3.55,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[4.50,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,3.60,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,3.19,0.00,2.69,0.00,0.00,0.00,4.12,0.00,0.00,0.00,3.75,0.00,0.00,0.00,4.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2.69,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[5.70,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,3.80,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,4.65,0.00,3.69,0.00,0.00,0.00,5.42,0.00,0.00,0.00,4.50,0.00,0.00,0.00,6.40,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,3.55,0.00,3.55,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[4.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,5.40,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,5.49,0.00,6.60,0.00,0.00,0.00,4.33,0.00,0.00,0.00,6.38,0.00,0.00,0.00,6.92,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,7.09,0.00,8.68,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,8.68,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,18.99,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,16.98,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,17.80,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,17.20,16.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,28.58,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,13.99,0.00,30.45,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,9.49,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,34.98,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,18.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,8.77,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,15.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,47.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,38.39,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,89.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,91.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,92.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,66.89,0.00,79.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,27.30,0.00,0.00,0.00,36.90,0.00,29.50,0.00,36.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,49.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,28.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,31.99,0.00,0.00,42.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,33.50],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,65.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,23.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,12.89,0.00,0.00,0.00,13.99,0.00,0.00,13.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,14.32,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,16.50,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,15.57,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,36.75,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,58.73,0.00,0.00,53.43,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,51.85,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,5.39,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,6.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,12.36,14.63,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,18.76,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,12.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,86.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,89.90,97.30,0.00,0.00,81.60,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,96.70,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,89.00,83.77,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,64.28,0.00,0.00,49.46,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,52.34,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,79.90,89.00,0.00,124.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,85.00,104.47,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,67.20,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,91.00,91.11,0.00,0.00,73.61,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,81.50,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,80.60,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,2.47,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2.44,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,28.44,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,15.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,15.10,0.00,0.00,13.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,22.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,31.92,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,28.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,22.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,8.55,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,62.70,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,8.30,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,62.70,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00]]
pp = np.array(pp)
#c1 = [26.0, 150.0, 300.0, 110.0, 400.0, 500.0, 200.0, 200.0, 27.0, 150.0, 50.0, 200.0, 75.0, 0.0, 250.0, 22.8, 300.0, 22.8, 22.8, 150.0, 300.0, 150.0, 100.0, 100.0, 1000.0, 150.0, 150.0, 200.0, 31.2, 100.0, 100.0, 50.0, 23.0, 300.0, 200.0, 300.0, 0.0, 300.0, 30.0, 26.0, 300.0, 300.0, 250.0, 100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 400.0, 21.2, 200.0, 500.0, 0.0]

m = GEKKO()
ni = 40
nj = 51

x = [[m.Var(lb=0,integer=True) for j in range(nj)] for i in range(ni)]

s = 0
expr = []
for i in range(ni):
    for j in range(nj):
        s += x[i][j]

for i in range(ni):
    expr.append(sum(x[i]))


for i in range(ni):
    for j in range(nj):
        if mm[i][j] == 0:
            m.Equation(x[i][j] == 0)



for i in range(ni):
    m.Equation(sum([x[i][j] for j in range(nj)]) >= qtde[i])



b = m.Array(m.Var,nj,integer=True,lb=0,ub=1)
iv = [None]*nj
for j in range(nj):
    iv[j] = m.sum([pp[i][j]*x[i][j] for i in range(ni)])
    m.Equation(iv[j] >= b[j]*c1[j])
    m.Equation((1 - b[j])*iv[j] == 0)

m.Obj(m.sum(expr))


m.options.SOLVER=1  # switch to APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-1',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 1000',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',\
                    'minlp_integer_leaves 2']

m.solve()
```

Edit: I have changed the writing of the last constraint as suggested by John Hedengren (bellow). However, with the insertion of the binary variable, the code now returns an error before starting any iterations. How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a binary variable (0=equipment off, 1=equipment on and above threshold) and equation as:

```py
b = m.Array(m.Var,nj,integer=True,lb=0,ub=1)
iv = [None]*nj

for j in range(nj):
    iv[j] = m.sum([pp[i][j]*x[i][j] for i in range(ni)])
    m.Equation(iv[j] >= b[j]*c1[j])
    m.Equation((1-b[j])*iv[j] <= 0)

m.options.SOLVER = 1  # Change to MINLP solver
```

You can split out the summation into an intermediate variable `iv` because it is used in two equations. Another recommendation is to use `m.sum()` instead of `sum`. Using the Gekko summation is typically faster. There are also other ways to pose the problem but this may be the most reliable. I can't verify this solution because your script is missing some inputs. It helps on future posts to reduce the problem to a [Minimal and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that solutions can be verified. There is additional information on [logical conditions in optimization problems](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/LogicalConditions).

**Response to Edit**

The MINLP does not converge quickly because there are `nj x ni = 2040` binary variables. That is `2^2040` potential solutions. You can adjust solver settings to help it find at least one feasible solution.

```py
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.solve()  # sometimes it helps to solve with IPOPT first

m.options.SOLVER=1  # switch to APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-2',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',\
                    'minlp_integer_leaves 2']
m.solve()
```

There is additional description on the solver options on the [APOPT website](https://apopt.com/download.php).

**Response to Edit**

The error on the first MINLP iteration is because the problem is not feasible. If you switch to solver option `minlp_as_nlp 1` then you can see the first NLP problem fail to converge. You can also see this with the IPOPT solver if you switch to `m.options.SOLVER=3`.

```
EXIT: Converged to a point of local infeasibility.
Problem may be infeasible.
```

If you solve locally with `m=GEKKO(remote=False)` and open the run folder before the solve command with `m.open_folder()` then you can see the `infeasibilities.txt` file that will help you identify the infeasible equation. I suspect that the infeasibility is because of the equations `m.Equation(m.sum([x[i][j] for j in range(nj)]) >= qtde[i])` and `m.Equation(x[i][j] == 0)`. You can also try to identify an infeasible problem with `m.options.COLDSTART=2`. There is additional help on troubleshooting applications in [exercise 18 in the Gekko tutorials](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried in my code, but it didn't find any solutions. I edited my question, so it includes all the variables. Could you please check if I made some mistake, or the problem really has no solution?

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry. I edited my question to include all the variables, and I would be very thankful if you could still help me.

Comment: You have 2^2040 different possible solutions. MINLP problems can take much longer than NLP but there are options that you can explore with the MINLP solver. Here are some options: https://apopt.com/download.php  I added some additional comments to my response. APOPT found an integer solution after 832 NLP iterations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time. I have just one more question. Even with the changes in the solver options, the case in which I added the binary variable does not find any solution. Is there anything else I could do obtain a solution? Or should I accept the fact that there is no solution with the constraints I have?

Comment: There may be a solution but it may be taking the solver too long to evaluate all of the options. With the options that I showed and your data, it found a solution in 832 iterations. If you changed the problem then it may take more iterations to find a solution. You can't say that there isn't a solution until it evaluates all of the options but that may take too long. There are many methods to approximate an MINLP solution without using integer variables. Here is one example: https://www.mdpi.com/2227-9717/7/12/929

Comment: Sorry for taking your time again; I have changed the writing of the last constraint as suggested (the new code is now in the question). However, with the insertion of the binary variable, the code now returns an error before starting any iterations (prior to the addition of the binary variable, the code was running every iteration and then, after reaching the maximum, it was returning an error, after several minutes of processing; now, it runs for about a minute, does not show any iteration and then returns an error). How can this be prevented?